# Mounting an SMB share on a Monterey machine

Tags: mount, smb, monterey

I've already filed a bug report on this but…

I have a machine that I recently upgraded to Monterey.  It has an SMB share that I want to mount.  Before the upgrade to Monterey

`mount -t smbfs smb://user:pass@host/volume` worked.

Now that fails with an authentication error but copy and pasting the url into Finder connects properly.

I'm a bit stymied by this as this allows me to do some clever mount point things in scripts that a simple `open smb://user:pass@host/volume` doesn't allow with the link in /Volumes.

Is there some hidden flag or setting that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from Apple.  I had to turn on "NTML cacheing" in the sharing dialog.

[image]